# Where to find the full story of King Muchukunda?

Tags: scripture, krishna, gods, bhagavata-purana

In Joseph Campbell book "The Hero with a Thousand Faces", he wrote: an ancient Hindu warrior-king named Muchukunda. He was born from his father's left side, the father having swallowed by mistake a fertility potion that the Brahmins had prepared for his wife. Then he summarized Muchukunda's story.

Iam interested in this tale, so please can anyone give me sources about the full story of King Muchukunda. I want to know every detail before Muchukunda's born until his retreat from the world

Comment: The story is explained in answer to this question [What is the story behind this Vishnu - Muchukunda painting?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16219/5212). Bhagavata Purana has its story which is linked in that answer.

Comment: I need  sources for the full story not the summary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Joseph Campbell is wrong. The king who was born from his father's side is Māndhātā, the son of Yuvanāśva not Muchukunda. and it was from his right side not the left.

According to SB 9.6.30:

> tataḥ kāla upāvṛtte
>   kukṣiṁ nirbhidya dakṣiṇam
>   yuvanāśvasya tanayaś
>   cakravartī jajāna ha
>
> Thereafter, in due course of time, a son with all the good symptoms of a powerful king came forth from the **lower right side of King Yuvanāśva’s abdomen.**

Comment: I don't understand Ur answer..how come it is full story?, can u pls elaborate it?...u may read https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/6/38 & https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/51 & same story from Vishnu Puran..and Story of Tadakasura Sangram from few other Puranas...